# use htaccess to make the rewrite url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello all i am having a project where i need to convert this url www.domain.com/page.php?brand=abcd to www.domain.com/abcd

i know that this is possible with .htaccess file 
currently in my htaccess file i have folowing code

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.domain.com [L]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
     ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
    Options -Indexes
```

please help me to do this and what line should i add to .htaccess file to achive the purpose 
i tried adding

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?brand=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last rule should work for internal rewrite to `/page.php?brand=abcd`.

For redirecting `/page.php?brand=abcd` to `/abcd` you can use this new rule:

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?brand=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?brand=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: yes your code is working but it seems like that my previous code is not working when i add your code in my htaccess file the site dosent redirects the 404 error page

Comment: You still need to keep both `ErrorDocument` lines in your .htaccess. Also please try to keep one question per thread. If this problem is solved then accept the answer and post a new question for different problem.

Comment: i want to direct the user to domain.com/abcd if it exists otherwise direct them to 404 error page . actually i can direct for domain.com/abcd.php pages only

Comment: i'll accept this answer once this problem is solved why my site dosent redirects to 404 error page earlier it used to

Comment: How can `/abcd` be an existing page?

Comment: i want to direct the user to domain.com/abcd only if the url is domain.com/page.php?brand=abcd. not for domain.com/abcd.php

Comment: My 301 rule is ONLY redirecting `domain.com/page.php?brand=abcd`. That rule's regex cannot affect `domain.com/abcd.php` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can Try this

```
  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
    RewriteRule ^ http://litelmaxx.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


    Options -Indexes
```